# how can i use opencv in ros using kinect to detect objects?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to detect and recognize objects by using opencv with kinect v1 sensro, how can i do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234758/how-can-i-use-opencv-in-ros-using-kinect-to-detect-objects?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

use opencv bridge to connect ros with opencv. now u can communicate with opencv running programs.

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2016-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0